# Howto change the font color on the "Label/Edit" area of a DropDownList ComboBox with VCL Themes?

Tags: delphi

Delphi 11 VCL, Windows 11.

A combobox with csDropDown style has ListBox and Edit areas (controls).
On csDropDownList The Edit area changed to a Label (non editable), I'll call it Label area.

I would like to change the font color of Label area if ItemIndex is not equal to the Tag content, but still using Themes, to get modern UI.

I can almost do it with csOwnerDrawFixed style and ComboBox2DrawItem as follow:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox2DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  LStyles: TCustomStyleServices;
begin
  LStyles := StyleServices;

  with Control as TComboBox do
    begin
      Canvas.Brush.Color := LStyles.GetStyleColor(scComboBox);

      if (odComboBoxEdit in State) and (ItemIndex <> Tag) then
        Canvas.Font.Color  := clRed
      else
        Canvas.Font.Color  := LStyles.GetStyleFontColor(sfComboBoxItemNormal);

      Canvas.FillRect(Rect) ;
      Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left+2, Rect.Top, Items[Index]);
    end;
end;
```

It is doing the job, but the appearance is not the same as for csDropDownList style:

1. There is no Mouse Hover color

[image]

2. There is a black frame on the csOwnerDrawFixed as follow:

[image]

A) Is there a way to improve the appearance to be the same?

I have many combo-boxes in my program and I would like to Draw the "Label" area with tComboBox Sub class method instead of connecting each of the DrawItem event of all tComboBoxes to a routine as above.

B) how to do that (Sub class Item Drawing)?